# Best practice to make cleanup after Scala Future is complete

Tags: scala, future, resource-cleanup

I want to make some cleanup (like close db connection) after a `Future` is complete.
Currently I achieve it this way:

```scala
Future { ... } onComplete {
  case Success(v) =>
    // ...
    conn.close()
  case Failure(ex) =>
    // ...
    conn.close()
}
```

There's duplicate code and it's also tedious.
Is there any best practice to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the same action `conn.close()` is performed on both success and failure, consider executing it as a side-effect using [`andThen`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#andThen[U](pf:PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[T],U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) like so

```
Future { ... } andThen { _ => conn.close() }
```

Similarly, using `onComplete` we could do

```
Future { ... } onComplete { _ => conn.close() }
```

The difference between `andThen` and `onComplete` is that latter will return `Unit`, that is, discard the returned value of the `Future`.

Answer (score 1):

The sad truth is that Scala Futures don't have this basic feature built in. I would therefore strongly suggest using a modern effect system like ZIO or cats-effect, both of which solve this problem and a myriad of others that Futures have. The easiest way to do what you want is to use the `bracket` method:

https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_handling_resources

Now `bracket` works great, but there's a way that usually works even better: the `Managed` type. It's virtually impossible to write code that leaks resources if you consistently use `Managed` when acquiring resources:

https://zio.dev/docs/datatypes/datatypes_managed

That said,if you absolutely must use Futures, you'll have to write your own try-finally equivalent. Or you can use mine:

```
  def tryFinally[A](tryy: => Future[A])(finallyy: => Future[Any])(
  implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] =
    Future.fromTry(Try(tryy)).flatten.transformWith { t =>
      finallyy.flatMap((_: Any) => Future.fromTry(t))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `map`, you can do something like this:

```
val mapped: Future[String] = future.map(_ => "OK").recover{case _ => "KO"}
```

Comment: Using two calls when one would do is not good practice. Use a single call like `onComplete`, `andThen` or `transform`